# Multiple Dropdowns Menu Selection text using .on works only on first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is to select an `li` element from bootstrap dropdown and display it in the dropdown box. When I try, it only changes the text from the first dropdown and the second dropdown event doesn't work.

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle changetext" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Datatypes <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollbar" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Generic</li>
                                <li><a id="num">Number</a></li>
                                <li><a id="float">Float</a></li>
                                <li><a>Boolean</a></li>
                                <li><a>Character</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Geographical</li>
                                <li><a>Zip Code</a></li>
                                <li><a>City</a></li>
                                <li><a>Region</a></li>
                                <li><a>Countries</a></li>
                                <li><a>Latitude/Longitude</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle changetext" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Datatypes <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollbar" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" >
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Generic</li>
                                <li><a id="num">Number</a></li>
                                <li><a id="float">Float</a></li>
                                <li><a>Boolean</a></li>
                                <li><a>Character</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Geographical</li>
                                <li><a>Zip Code</a></li>
                                <li><a>City</a></li>
                                <li><a>Region</a></li>
                                <li><a>Countries</a></li>
                                <li><a>Latitude/Longitude</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
```

For these two dropdown menus, I want to display the text on selection inside the below element:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle changetext" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Datatypes <span class="caret"></span></button>
```

I use jQuery for making the selection and displaying, but it happens only to the first dropdown menu.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click",function(){
  $(".changetext").text($(this).text());
   )}
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle to let us know your problem better?

Comment: You are applying the same anonymous function to all `a` elements across both dropdowns which will change the button text of Both buttons for any `a` clicked.  Is this what you want?  You do not differente between the dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click",function(){

  $(".changetext").text($(".changetext").text() + ' ' + $(this).text());

  });

});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/bLts45po/

Comment: No, Here I need to change the selection text of each button separately based on   drop down of respective one but your code changes the second button text on selecting from first button and also it gets appended

Comment: @chandrapavan you need change both drop down?

Comment: Yes, but both dropdowns are separate and they have same data inside dropdown menu

Comment: @chandrapavan no problem, you accept my answer and close the discussion

Comment: can you check this.. I need to replace the button text to selection text but not appending.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("div.dropdown").find("button").text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle changetext" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Datatypes <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollbar" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Generic</li>
    <li><a id="num">Number</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="float">Float</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Boolean</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Character</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Geographical</li>
    <li><a>Zip Code</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>City</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Region</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Countries</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Latitude/Longitude</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle changetext" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Datatypes <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollbar" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Generic</li>
    <li><a id="num">Number</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="float">Float</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Boolean</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Character</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Geographical</li>
    <li><a>Zip Code</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>City</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Region</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Countries</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Latitude/Longitude</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this code `$(".dropdown-menu li a")` has a length of 18 elements

this code `$(".changetext")` has a length of 2 elements

for every `a` clicked in either drop-down you are changing both buttons.
Make sure this is the behavior you want, because this is what your JQuery code is doing.

You need to isolate the clicked elements to act on the button associated with the dropdown.

This code will apply the same click function to all `$(".dropdown-menu li a")` elements, ***but*** will change the text of the `button` closest to the clicked element in the DOM

```
$("div.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function(event) {
  $(this).closest("div.dropdown").find("button").text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: No, what I needed is changing the Button text based on the dropdown selected, but when the code executes it either changes for only first dropdown or it changes all the buttons text to same selection of the first dropdown

Comment: No, I don't want that.

Comment: you miss my point - the code you posted **is** doing that - you need to differentiate the drop-downs and the buttons